# Blockchain Explorer for local full node

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node, c#, nbitcoin, blockchain-explorer

I would like to build my own blockchain explorer because I have found that using the API's of 3rd party blockchain explorers only gives me around 2 or 3 requests per second.

Does an open source project already exists which will let me explorer my local copy of the bitcoin-core blockchain?

Ideally, I would like to:

1. Index all transactions into a local database such as MySQL to make searches faster,
2. Be able to search by tx, address, public key, block number etc,
3. Would be nice if it can interface with NBitcoin so I can code with C#.

Any recommendations will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You could check https://github.com/Blockstream/esplora
I think it ticks all of the boxes, I am not sure about the NBitcoin though.

Comment: This looks good.  Any idea if they have some good documentation and example usage which is better than the few lines written on their github page.

Answer (score 2):

You can use my blockchain parser (python script) that converts the local copy of blockchain (blkXXXXX.dat files) to human readable text view -> [my parser](https://github.com/ragestack/blockchain-parser)

Bases on this parser you can do anything you want with that data.